# Firesbase authentication iOS login get user detail

Tags: ios, swift4

I have just followed and correctly added the following tutorial to my app. But I’m struggling on how to get the ‘logged in’ users details from the Firestore database?

The Tutorial:

https://youtu.be/1HN7usMROt8

Once the user registers through my app the ‘First name’, ‘last name’ and ‘UID’ are saved by the Firestore database. But once the user logs in how do I GET the users first name to copy to a label on a welcome screen inside the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you know how Firestore works. If you don't you can get all information in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or watch [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) about Firestore on YouTube.

So let's say you have your users saved in collection named **users**. When the user sign in you can get current user like this:

```swift
let currentSignInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser!
```

If you will force unwrap it make sure that user will be **signed in**.

When you have current user you can get his UID by calling `uid` property of current user:

```swift
let currentUserID = currentSignInUser.uid
```

Now you can query this UID to get documents from Firestore **users** collection that have same UID field value as your current signed in user:

```swift
let query = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("UID", isEqualTo: currentUserID)
```

Make sure that the first parameter of `whereField()` function is same as your field name in documents. Because you mentioned that UID is saved to database I named it UID.

This is all for getting information of your current user and making query out of it. Now you can GET documents from Firestore:

```swift
query.getDocuments() { [weak self] (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            if let userInfo = querySnapshot?.documents.first { 
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Set label text to first name
                    self?.youLabel.text = userInfo["firstName"]
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Change `userInfo` key to whatever name have you used for storing first name in Firestore. For example if you named your document field `firstName` then `userInfo` dictionary key must be **firstName**.

Comment: Brilliant that’s great I’ll try it out later.

Comment: I got it working but had to replace the   `"Firestore.firestore().getDocuments` with `query.getDocuments` So now I can get data from the database, but how would I update existing data like a bool? with again the current logged in user?

Comment: Ok thank you for your excellent work. I read to change a field in Firestore you would use ‘update’ but still cannot seem to get it to work? Wouldn’t you use something like `Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("UID", isEqualTo: currentUserID).update`

Comment: Just an Bool field that is in the logged in users collection. I have set, "firstname", "secondname", and 1 Boolean named "testpassed" when the user registers in the app for the first time the boolean is set to 'false', but when they pass a test within the app this boolean should be set to 'true'. I'm guessing that you would firstly have to get the users UID again like we did before to get the bool to change it to 'true'?

Comment: Okey I get it. ```userInfo``` variable that I declared in last code snippet has ```reference``` property. You must always have reference to manipulate data in firebase, this could be Collection or Document reference. In your case you can get reference with ```userInfo.reference```then you can call ```updateData(["testpassed": true])``` or pass in any other value that you want to update on this specific document. Remember that it must be dictionary and keys must be the same as your fields name. Same goes for values, they must have same data type that you specified in firebase.

Comment: Yes that seems to work now like you mentioned above I used  `userInfo.reference.updateData(["testpassed":true]);` Great stuff thanks again